# How to execute code in resize function when the webpage loads without having to rewrite it outside the resize function in javascript (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

It's kinda hard to explain for me, but I'll give an example.

Let's take this function:

```
$(window).resize(()=>{
    if(window.innerHeight < 500){
        $wrapper.height('100vh')
    }
    else{
        $wrapper.height('60vh')
    }
})
```

Of course this code doesn't execute without resizing the window, so I have to write it again outside the resize function, so it works all the time, just like that:

```
if(window.innerHeight < 500){
    $wrapper.height('100vh')
}
else{
    $wrapper.height('60vh')
}
```

Is there a way not to repeat the code like in the example above? Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the callback you pass to `.resize` outside, once. Then, call it, and also pass it as a callback:

```
const handleResize = () => {
  if(window.innerHeight < 500){
      $wrapper.height('100vh')
  }
  else{
      $wrapper.height('60vh')
  }
};
handleResize();
$(window).resize(handleResize);
```